# Why am I getting admob clicks before iphone app is released

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, admob

The past couple of iphone apps I have released have gotten clicks on admob before they even get released to the appstore!  I do not know what's going on.  Every time I test I always use the xcode simulator which uses test ads and I never install on my iphone!  I do not want to get my admob account banned.  Does anybody have any ideas about what is going on?  I tried using different phones to archive and upload my build but still this problem persists.  I have looked everywhere and I have not found anybody who has had this same problem.  Is it maybe incorrectly displaying where the revenue is coming from?  Also any time a test interstitial popped up on the simulator, I never clicked on it, always x'ed it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various possibilities:

It is possible that also the test ads are counted.

Apple review team may be playing with the app.

You are not always connected to the test Ad service.

Comment: do you know if there is anyway I can see the time in which the click happened? @Vincent

Comment: No, as far as i know, that is not possible

Answer (score 0):

i think that making sure that test ads are turned on and not counted on Admob's side would be a solution.  also this link might be useful https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2753860?hl=en